# Бот не отправляет сообщение с помощью php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Всем привет, бот не отправляет сообщение через срипт php, но если ввожу ссылку с параметрами в браузере, то срабатывает.

```
    $website="https://api.telegram.org/bot*TOKEN*";
$chatId=USER_ID;  
$params=[
     'chat_id'=>$chatID,
     'text'=>'MoonLight',
 ];
 $ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Все работает без ошибок, запросы уходят? Глянь логи

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php#108309

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/52944

Comment: Времени нет разбираться, вот - может поможет

Comment: Скрипт срабатывает без ошибок.
предварительно в браузере подключил вебхук
https://api.telegram.org/bot*token*/setWebhook?url=https://*site*/bot.php
и получил результат {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
Но когда пишу боту, он ничего не отправляет на скрипт

Comment: $result возвращает NULL или что?

Comment: самым полезным в данном случае, чем я могу тебе помочь - это Debug, я надеюсь ты используешь нормальную IDE, вроде PhpStorm(это не реклама). Там по строчкам можешь увидеть что к чему

Comment: В OpenServer удобные логи, там я могу глянуть исходящие и входящие запросы, мб у тебя тоже есть такая возможность

Comment: Скрипт на хостинге стоит, не локально.
$result возвращает bool(false)

Comment: Локально работает, а на хостинге нет.

Comment: Хостинг в России, телега там заблочена. Прокси решили проблему